# Comparing logistic regression models of winning percentage

Tags: error, logistic

I previously asked this question: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24194/winning-percentage-logistic-regression-or-linear-regression)

I've generated the two logistic regression models described in the link using all available data (8 seasons for all 30 teams), and now I want to decide which is a better predictor of win percentage in the coming season, winning percentage in the previous season or Pythagorean expectation from the previous season.

I know that if you want to evaluate the predictive abilities of a model, it's often good to evaluate on data different from that which generated the model. I wonder how important that is here, given that the models are of the same type, created from the same data. It seems as though we could say that the model which was a better fit with respect to the data which created both models is better in this case.

So, the question is: 1) do I need to see how the models compare on a different data set, and 2) what's the standard measure for model comparison in a situation like that I've described.

Basically, how do I know which is better?

Comment: To elaborate on the second paragraph, my understanding is when comparing models, we normally cross validate to make sure we're not overestimating the predictive ability of model 1 relative to model 2 based on model 1 having been overfit. But in the situation I've described above, overfitting doesn't seem like much of a concern, since the models are of the same complexity and they were trained on the same data set. I'm new to this stuff, so perhaps I'm thinking about this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

All of these can be useful depending on the data set: [accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy#In_binary_classification), [ROC curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Basic_concept), [area under ROC curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_Under_Curve). These metrics have to be calculated on a hold-out data set (not used in model training) in order to avoid over-fitting bias.

Given that team's wins/losses are relatively balanced, accuracy might work reasonably well (it requires choosing a probability threshold though)